# Insert value into column if another column's value is present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert a value into a dataframe column if another column's value is present in another dataframe. I wish to achieve this in a time-efficient manner. I have tried looping using iloc, but it takes too long. I have looked into list comprehension or .apply() but did not find a solution.

I have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [2,1,4,3,3,1,2,3,1]})
```

and:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [4,1,5,2,3]}, {"Col2":[22,11,44,33,55])
```

and wish to add a column to df1 if value in df1'Col1' equals value in df2'Col1':

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [2,1,4,3,3,1,2,3,1]}, {"Col_new":[33,11,22,55,55,11,33,55,11]})
```

I tried:

```
df1['Col_new]=np.nan

for i in range(len(df2)):
df1.Col_new=df1.Col_new.replace(df1[df1['Col1']==df2.iloc[i,0]].Col_new,df2.iloc[i,1])
```

Comment: pls paste the code, so we know the code that is not working for you or is inefficient.

Comment: Can you clarify what the operation you're trying to perform is?

Comment: @AMC I have two dataframes. One with information for each user such as time, point-of-interest ID (POI ID), etc. And another one with location (GPS latitude/longitude) information for each POI ID that I retrived. Now I want to match/merge the latitude/longitude values of df2 into the rows with identical POI ID of df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) left:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 3},
                    "Col2": {0: 22, 1: 11, 2: 44, 3: 33, 4: 55}})

# Left Merge
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Col1', how='left')
# For Display
print(merged.to_string(index=False))
```

`merged`:

```
Col1  Col2
   2    33
   1    11
   4    22
   3    55
   3    55
   1    11
   2    33
   3    55
   1    11
```